# Match first word of a phrase in a String

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, google-toolbox-for-mac

I am using the GTMRegex class from the Google toolbox for mac (in a Cocoa / Objective-C) app:

http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/

I need to do a match and replace of a 3 word phrase in a string. I know the 2nd and 3rd words of the phrase, but the first word is unknown.

So, if I had:

lorem BIFF BAM BOO ipsem

and

lorem BEEP BAM BOO ipsem

I would watch to match both (BEEP BAM BOO) and (BIFF BAM BOO). I then want to wrap them in bold HTML tags.

Here is what I have:

```
GTMRegex *requiredHeroRegex = [GTMRegex regexWithPattern:@"(\\([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\\b Hero Required)" options:kGTMRegexOptionSupressNewlineSupport|kGTMRegexOptionIgnoreCase];
out = [requiredHeroRegex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:out withReplacement:@"<b>\\1</b>"];
```

However, this is not working. basically, I cant figure out how to match the first word when I dont know it.

Anyone know the RegEx to do this?

Update:

GTRegEx uses POSIX 1003.2 Regular Expresions, so the solution is:

```
GTMRegex *requiredHeroRegex = [GTMRegex regexWithPattern:@"([[:<:]][A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[[:>:]])( Hero Required)" options:kGTMRegexOptionSupressNewlineSupport|kGTMRegexOptionIgnoreCase];
out = [requiredHeroRegex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:out withReplacement:@"<b>\\1\\2</b>"];
```

Note the crazy syntax for the word boundaries.

Update 2 : Here is the JavaScript version:

```
/(([A-Za-z]*?|[A-Za-z]*? [A-Za-z]*?)( Hero Required))/gm
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `" .*? Hero Required"`, however, it will not catch phrase if it is the start of the sentence.
For both cases use `"( .*? Hero Required|^.*? Hero Required)"`.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those match anything.

Comment: i verified it with regexbuddy, so i assume the problem is in the code, not the regex part, and i don't know cocoa...

Comment: Or it could be that that syntax just doesnt work with GTMRegex.

Comment: GTRegEx uses POSIX 1003.2 Regular Expresion. I posted the solution in the original message.

Comment: @mikechambers post it as an answer and accept it so that this question will appear solved in the listings.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\b([a-z][a-z0-9]*)( second third)` with `<b>\1</b>\2`

Comment: That also does not match anything.